# Searching node in list both works and does not work

Tags: c, list, search, linked-list, strcmp

This might be a bad question but I'm completly lost. I have this code:

```
struct nodoTemas* search_in_list(char * val, struct nodoTemas **prev,struct nodoTemas *head/*, struct nodoTemas *curr*/)
{
struct nodoTemas *ptr = head;
struct nodoTemas *tmp = NULL;
bool found = false;

printf("\n Searching the list for value [%s] \n",val);

while(ptr != NULL)
{
    if(ptr->nombreTema == val)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {

        tmp = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

if(true == found)
{
    if(prev)
        *prev = tmp;
    return ptr;
}
else
{
    return NULL;//si no ha encontrado nada devuelve NULL
}
```

}

And I test it, in a specific file to test it, like this:

```
char * var="tema1";
char * var2="tema2";
head=add_to_list(var,true,head,curr);
curr=head;
curr=add_to_list(var2,true,head,curr);
struct nodoTemas* nodoBuscado;
char *temaABuscar="tema4";
nodoBuscado=search_in_list(temaABuscar, NULL,head);

if(nodoBuscado!=NULL)
    printf("VALOR DEL NODO %s\n",nodoBuscado->nombreTema);
```

And it works perfectly fine no matter what I do. If I look for something that exists it prints it and so on. Now on my main file I get the char * my server gets the char * from a message. I thought this failed so I tried several things, this being one of them:

```
printf("MATCH %d \n" , strcmp(temaRecibido,head->nombreTema));
```

And I get a 0 as a result. So the strings are the same. But the search fails, in this other file. I've printed it, I've checked for their strlen sizes, and it all matches.

So I believe I'm looking at the wrong side but I cannot understand why code that is working in one place does not work in other. Should I look for the mistake somewhere else? Also, if I do strlen of a string WITH null and one without null, are they the same size? man says it excludes the terminating byte but I am unsure about this.

I'm sorry if the post is lacking I wasn't sure how to properly present it.

Comment: I would think knowing what `add_to_list` does (rather than asking us to trust its namesake) would be relevant to your question. Also, wouldn't it be constructive to also search for something that is known to be *in the list* as opposed to something that is clearly *not* before claiming "it works perfectly fine".?

Comment: In C, you don't compare "strings" with "==" generally. You use `str*cmp()` or other similar functions. Otherwise you're just comparing the memory addresses where the strings start...

Comment: Many problems exist. I do not think it is to operate normally.

Comment: @WhozCraig I always doubt just how much code should I put in this type of questions because I write a bit too much so I try to address the topic briefly and with the right amount of info. For the future, would dumping 100 lines of code  be better?

Comment: @keont Enough to reproduce the issue is usually both sufficient and preferable, i.e. a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare strings like

```
if(ptr->nombreTema == val)
```

You should use strcmp

```
if(strcmp(ptr->nombreTema, val) == 0)
```

Comment: You are completly correct. I'm ashamed to say this is not the bazillion time I've done that same mistake. I have it right in other places of the same code but not there. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

im not sure if you can compare strings in C that way...
if you search for the string "tema1" instead a pointer to "tema1" what is the result?
also, check this http://www.wikihow.com/Compare-Two-Strings-in-C-Programming.

Comment: yep, I've done this mistake several times and it seems like it's taking me some time to get it right, this is correct.